# jta-data-source understanding

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

Приветствую! Есть файл persistence.xml, в нем строка

`<jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/default</jta-data-source>`

Гуглив понял, что этот тег отвечает за поиск источника данных. Но что это за name space такой comp/env/jdbc/default? Как я могу посмотреть что в default? И еще гуглив нашел предложение, которое говорит, что если указать properties для подключения к БД, то можно не устанавливать jta-data-source. Так ли это?

Comment: Плохо гуглили :) Это [JNDI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/). Почему такой формат имени можете посмотреть [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19747-01/819-0079/dgjndi.html#wp19252). Что касается ответа на ваш вопрос в целом, то вот разрернутый на [enSO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1990914/5694145). Надеюсь поможет.